# How to store large number of ngrams efficently?

Tags: database, database-design, machine-learning, data-mining, n-gram

I am extracting 4-grams from binary items in hexadecimal form, this mean I can have at most 65535 different grams per item.

I want to associate every item to it's grams and their frequency but I am puzzled on how to store everything – this is my first data mining experience and I don't have any clue about best practices and common tools.

I was trivially thinking to build a big table in a relational database with a schema like `(ITEM-NAME, GRAM1, GRAM2... GRAM65535)` and store inside it the frequencies but I can see this approach is uber impratical because of the number of columns.

I know there must be better solutions out there but I don't know where to look at.

Suggestions?

Comment: is the resulting "matrix" sparse? I.e. can you expect that, on average, at least half of the GRAMn...GRAM65535 values for a given Item can be 0?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to store ngram is [prefixTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) IMHO.
Is is used to in very efficient library lingpipe.

Example of tree:

```
 1. gr1
   1. gr2 (item1)
   2. gr3 (item2,item3,item4)
 2. gr3 (item1, tem2)
 3. gr2
  1. g3 (item5,item6)
  2. g4 (item1)
```

Other option is to store in format of inverted index:
ngramm -> item

```
gr1 (item1, item2)
gr2 (item1, item3)
gr3 (item2, item3)
gr4 (item1, item2)
```

Note: Second option does not store order information which is crucial for ngram...